# How do I change the following vertical list to horizontal list?

Tags: html, css

The following coding gives an output of a list in a vertical manner. How do I adjust this to make it in horizantal list? For example like this: http://www.nol.com.sg/wps/portal/nol

```
    <body>
        <ul id="mainmenu">
            <li><a class="menu" href="">Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="menu" href="">Company</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a class="menu" href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: in css #mainmenu > li{display:inline or inline-block} should help

Comment: How can I make the Menu,Company and Contact Us into horizontal?

Comment: are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/J592A/1/

Comment: Well no but I've got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J592A/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a class="menu" href="">Menu</a>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">About</a>                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="">Company</a>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">History</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">News</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="">Contact Us</a>

        </li></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainmenu li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:1px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
#mainmenu li li {
    float:none;
    padding:0;
}
#mainmenu li ul {
    display:none;
    padding:0;
}
#mainmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In css use the following code:

```
#mainmenu li{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

**CSS**

```
#navcontainer ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `inline` and `inline-block` will make browsers interpret the newline between each `li` as a space character, adding a gap which cannot be controlled by `margin` between each `li`. `float: left` avoids this (but has other issues of course). See http://jsfiddle.net/Tuq3N/

Answer (score 0):

To affect this only on li  that are childs of #mainmenu

```
#mainmenu > li {
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J592A/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a class="menu" href="">Menu</a>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">About</a>                
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="">Company</a>        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">History</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">News</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="">Contact Us</a>

        </li></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainmenu li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:1px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
#mainmenu li li {
    float:none;
    padding:0;
}
#mainmenu li ul {

    padding:0;
}
#mainmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```